# How to remove the gap between the bars in a bar chart

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have created a Bar chart(having total 4 bars), wherein there is a gap between these bars.
Kindly let me know , how to remove this gap between the bars as there is no inbuild property available...

Comment: How are you generating the bars (what code are you using).  If you are using whole integer pixel numbers instead of decimal numbers then it should be fairly easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but here is the solution for any one else that is looking for it.

The property:           columnWidthRatio="1"

On  component sets the column with to be 100 % of the radio, meaning that it fills all space between columns.

Hope it helps,

B.P.